# Alternative word for pajama?

Tags: etymology, word-usage

When I first saw the word "pajama", I felt it doesn't sound like an English word. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pajama says it's from Hindi and Urdu and showed up after 1883.  I'm just curious, how did native English speaker say "pajama" before 1883?

Comment: Nightgown? Nightshirt?

Comment: Sleeper? PJ's? skivvies?

Comment: *Night gown* is attested by the OED in 1475; *night robe* in 1553; *night shirt* in 1657. But apparently the English needed to import an Indian word because they didn't wear *night trousers* before they conquered India and learned how comfortable they were.

Answer (score 2):

The word didn't pre-exist because the garments didn't exist. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pajamas#History):

> 1828: "His chief joy smoking a cigar in loose Paee-jams and native slippers." Orient. Sport. Mag. reprint 1873, i. 64. 1881:
>
> "The rest of our attire consisted of that particularly light and airy white flannel garment, known throughout India as a pyjama suit." Haekel, Ceylon, p. 329.[Yule, Henry and A.C. Burnell. Pyjammas, p748.]

The garments had been introduced briefly in the 17th century but went out of fashion. They were re-introduced into the Westsern world about 1870.